# How to write a boolean query in searchkick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

I am trying to write a boolean query search, using searchkick, that returns all records where term A is mentioned along with term B or C,

A AND (B OR C)

After reading the docs it would seem that this is the format I need to match the above criteria,

```
conditions = { _and: [
    {_or: [{title: "B"}, {title: 'C'}] }
  ]
}

Model.search "A", where: conditions
```

I would expect to see results returned for this query but no results are returned. I've double checked that there are documents that would meet the criteria. Any ideas on what needs to be tweaked?

A few references,

https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/issues/1284

https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/issues/1324